# Inside Ckeditor if I type text or backspace input checkbox will uncheck and value will change

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I change any text or give backspace checkbox will unchecked and value will 0 in Ckeditor. I tried but I can't do it. How can I solve this problem?

```js
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="description" value="1" checked>
    <textarea name="editor1">Lorem ipsum dolor amet</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen event `change` of CKEDITOR.instances

```
        const checkbox = document.getElementById('description');
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
        for (const i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function () {
                checkbox.checked = false;
                checkbox.value = 0;
            });
        }
```

or instance that you need

```
        const checkbox = document.getElementById('description');
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
        CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('change', function () {
            checkbox.checked = false;
            checkbox.value = 0;
        });
```